# ambiguous scrollable content uiscrollview swift

Tags: swift

Всем привет. Я знаю, что тема UIScrollView в Swift многократно обсуждалась, и имеется много видео и статей, как пофиксить ошибку ambiguous scrollable content. Но, как правило, все эти обсуждения и статьи касаются содержимого contentView, т. е. контейнера, который кладётся в собственно ScrollView, который уже наполняется содержимым. Моя проблема вот в чем. Я добавляю ScrollView во View Controller, назначаю ему нулевые constraints по всем четырем сторонам, contentView ещё даже и не пахнет, я его ещё не добавил, а мне XCode уже пишет эти волшебные слова - has ambiguous scrollable content height/weight. Так каким же образом "прилепить" ScrollView к Safe Area, чтобы XCode это принял и не ругался?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вас беспокоит это предупреждение в интерфейс билдере, вы можете отключить его, выбрав в свойствах вашего `UIScrollView` в разделе `Size Inspector` в самом низу `Ambiguity > Never Verify`

**Дополнение касательно Content Layout Guides**

Действительно, как указано в комментарии, если снять указанную галку, ошибка исчезает, поскольку мы даем понять, что не намерены использовать новые свойства `UIScrollView`, появившиеся в iOS 11, а именно [contentLayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2865870-contentlayoutguide?language=objc) и [frameLayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2865772-framelayoutguide?language=objc). Вместе с тем это довольно полезные свойства, позволяющие располагать элементы внутри скролл вью относительно соответственно границ его содержимого или внешних границ.

Разница показана на гифке. `Content Label` прикреплен к `contentLayoutGuide`, а `Frame Label` прикреплен к `frameLayoutGuide`, также добавлена вьюшка для скроллинга

Подробнее данные свойства освещены например [здесь](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/easier-scrolling-with-layout-guides/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос не в том, что беспокоит, вопрос в том, что если не обращать внимание на это предупреждение и добавить в ScrollView contentView, связать его соответствующими констрейнтами, установить высоте низкий приоритет, задать соответствие высоты и ширины к ScrollView, накидать в него View - то сборка проекта заканчивается успешно, но на экране эмулятора ничего не отображается

Comment: Вопрос у вас как раз про предупреждение при пустом скролл вью, теперь вы ведете речь уже про добавление в него содержимого, которое почему-то не отображается. В таком случае дополните вопрос,  представив иерархию вьюшек внутри скролл вью с имеющимися констрейнтами

Comment: Спасибо, решение найдено, совершенно случайно.

Comment: @АлександрЗарудний Будьте добры, опишите ваше решение. Это многим поможет

Comment: Как я описал выше, проблема была в том, что изначально при добавлении в корневой View элемента Scroll View и назначении ему нулевых constraint ко всем сторонам, как и требуется сделать по всем урокам, что я видел, XCode выдает ошибку. Это еще до наполнения Scroll View содержимым. Решение: в сториборде нужно выделить Scroll View, открыть в свойствах раздел с геометрией элемента (в правом углу там где значок маленькая линейка) и в пункте Content Insets снять галочку с параметра Content Layout Guides. Может опытные разработчики на iOs подскажут, что это за параметр и на что он влияет

Comment: @АлександрЗарудний см мой дополненный ответ

Answer (score 0):

[image: Убрать галочку с этого пункта]

Выделить в сториборде Scroll View, убрать галочку с пункта на скрине